# How to get path to firefox.exe and equiv in other os

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to get the location to the main firefox application so I can use nsIProcess to open it.

[MDN article on nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess)

Using this code i can get the folder this app could be in:

```
alert(Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties).get("CurProcD", Ci.nsIFile).path)
//returns C:\Program Files\Aurora\browser
```

[MDN article on nsIDirectoryService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsDirectoryService)

However in windows its firefox.exe i dont know what it would be in other operating systems. So is there any universal cross platform verison to get the main launcher file which I can then open like this:

```
var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
process.init(execFile);
var args = ["-safe-mode"];
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the (obsure) key `XREExeF`

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var exefile = FileUtils.getFile("XREExeF", [])
```

Comment: No way! This is so cool thanks paa! Will this get the appropriate fill in other os'es? I was doing research and found that in mac it is `firefox-bin` and in linux it is just `firefox` and in sh it is `firefox.sh` in debian its `/usr/bin/iceweasel`? lol im not sure about debian and in gnu its `icecat`? not sure about that gnu one either lol

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work across every platform. Also being part of the XUL runtime means it is not specific to Firefox.